# Spring - referenceData Best Practice

Tags: spring

Scenario:
I have the list of states ( of USA) stored in the database. I need to display the states list in a form.jsp. I query the database and get the list of states in the referenceData method so that the list of states will be available when the form loads.

Question:
Since the referenceData is executed on each page refresh, isn't it a drag to query the database on each refresh? Does Spring cache this internally or is it an expensive database query call each time?

What is the optimal way to populate the states drop down on form load in Spring?

Comment: You don't tell us how you get the states, so it's hard to answer. If you haven't configured any cache, anywhere, it won't be cached anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring doesn't cache anything if not asked explicitly. On the other hand you can configure your persistence provider (e.g. [Hibernate query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache)) or use built-in Spring [caching abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

Is it an overkill to query the database on each page refresh? In your circumstances: fixed list that changes very rarely and has very few items - I would even say load it once and keep it for the lifetime of the application. Make a back-door in case you need to modify. Or use cache with very long expiry date.

On the other hand caching is often painful, especially when caching validation comes into play. But in your situation, what can wrong?<sup>*famous last words*</sup>

Comment: It's the list of states in USA. Don't think that'll change in the near future not-to-mention between page refresh! The list is stored in the database. A neat one place for all applications to access. So, I need to query the database for the list and populate the ModelMap...but just dont want to query on each refresh. Any ideas what the best practice is in this case?

Comment: @rprab: look again at my post. I actually advice either using some caching or simply loading the list once on startup and keeping it in memory. The list is small and constant enough to make this approach feasible.